# How do I access and modify variables declared inside MainActivity class inside its class function?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to access and modify btnClick variable declared inside MainActivity function, how do I do it?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var btnClick = true
        randomlyChangeDrawable()
    }

    fun randomlyChangeDrawable() {
        btnClick = false
    }
}
```

Comment: @Eugene edit approved, but you could have eventually corrected the title too: see my subsequent edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you move btnClick outside of onCreate method, it will be accessible from all method in MainActivity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var btnClick = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btnClick = true
        randomlyChangeDrawable()
    }

    fun randomlyChangeDrawable() {
        btnClick = false
    }
}
```

this is not specific for android classes. every variable that declare inside a class(not inside it methods), is accessible inside all methods in that class

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice I was trying to access a variable declared inside a member function inside MainActivity till now.

Answer (score -2):

You can declare the variable on top 
`var btnclicked`;

Basic example using kotlin

```
var btnClicked=false;
fun main() {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
    btnClicked=true;
    otherFn()
}

fun otherFn(){
    println(btnClicked) //prints true
    btnClicked=false;
    println(btnClicked) //prints false
}
```

Comment: Because the introduction of a global variable is unnecessary, the original question was about classes and fields.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i was trying to provide an example in kotlin, which is similar to the answer written below by shahab

Comment: it is not similar

Comment: It is not similar, you are using a global variable while they are using a class field; and therefore your answer is still wrong in the original context